# How i can add my plugin to list plugins for react-leaflet?

Tags: react-leaflet

I was created plugin, that is https://github.com/argonavt11/leaflet-react-track-player. How this do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fork react-leaflet.

Edit this page: https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/edit/master/docs/plugins.md

Submit a PR with your changes.